# SQL “For XML Path” - multiple nested results with null type

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, path, null

I will make a block code to a simple example of what i need

```
select      
    (   select
                (Select
                    (Select             
                            NULLIF (t1.number,2) as 'e'
                    FOR XML PATH('d'),type
                    ) 
                FOR XML PATH('c'),type
                ) 
        FOR XML PATH('b1'), type
    ) ,
    t1.number as 'b2'
from
(select 1 as number union all select 2 as number union all select 3 as number) as t1
FOR XML PATH(''), 
ROOT('a')
```

and with this code i obtain:

```
<a>
  <b1>
    <c>
      <d>
        <e>1</e>
      </d>
    </c>
  </b1>
  <b2>1</b2>
  <b1>
    <c>
      <d />
    </c>
  </b1>
  <b2>2</b2>
  <b1>
    <c>
      <d>
        <e>3</e>
      </d>
    </c>
  </b1>
  <b2>3</b2>
</a>
```

but i want to obtain when number  is 2 the c and d and d element does not show
(remember this is as example of a more complex query)

What i want to obtain:

```
<a>
  <b1>
    <c>
      <d>
        <e>1</e>
      </d>
    </c>
  </b1>
  <b2>1</b2>
  </b1>
  <b2>2</b2>
  <b1>
    <c>
      <d>
        <e>3</e>
      </d>
    </c>
  </b1>
  <b2>3</b2>
</a>
```

Comment: Your XML you *want to obtain* is not valid... Please repair this and please provide a little background about your needs. T

Comment: you are right  there is a > just before "as t1" copy paste problems thanks,  it's corrected now.

Comment: No, this error was easy to detect (and repair). The XML as you post it in the *want to obtain* section is not valid (I guess there's a `</b1>` in the wrong place)

Comment: just change to <b1></b1> instead of only </1>, I don't know why, but that xml is the response of the query i posted.

Answer (score 0):

My magic crystall ball tells me, that - eventually - you are looking for this:

```
select
    CASE WHEN t1.number<>2 THEN      
    (   select
                (Select
                    (Select             
                            t1.number 'e'
                    FOR XML PATH('d'),type
                    ) 
                FOR XML PATH('c'),type
                ) 
        FOR XML PATH('b1'), type
    ) END,
    t1.number as 'b2'
from
(select 1 as number union all select 2 as number union all select 3 as number) as t1
FOR XML PATH(''), 
ROOT('a')
```

The result

```
<a>
  <b1>
    <c>
      <d>
        <e>1</e>
      </d>
    </c>
  </b1>
  <b2>1</b2>
  <b2>2</b2>
  <b1>
    <c>
      <d>
        <e>3</e>
      </d>
    </c>
  </b1>
  <b2>3</b2>
</a>
```

### UPDATE: A sedond guess...

```
select
    ISNULL(CASE WHEN t1.number<>2 THEN      
    (   select
                (Select
                    (Select             
                            t1.number 'e'
                    FOR XML PATH('d'),type
                    ) 
                FOR XML PATH('c'),type
                ) 
        FOR XML PATH(''), type
    ) END,'') AS b1,
    t1.number as 'b2'
from
(select 1 as number union all select 2 as number union all select 3 as number) as t1
FOR XML PATH(''), 
ROOT('a')
```

returns

```
<a>
  <b1>
    <c>
      <d>
        <e>1</e>
      </d>
    </c>
  </b1>
  <b2>1</b2>
  <b1></b1>
  <b2>2</b2>
  <b1>
    <c>
      <d>
        <e>3</e>
      </d>
    </c>
  </b1>
  <b2>3</b2>
</a>
```

Comment: thanks mate, i just simplify the query and put  NULLIF (t1.number,2) as an example to have null there. This do not solve my problem. What i want is when i get nill in that type, and no rows in that type or upper type, that elements doesn't show.

Comment: @Armando The expected output - as you show it at the moment - is not correct. How should I know what you need. What **exactly** is wrong with my output?

Comment: because the solution (CASE WHEN t1.number<>2 THEN  ) here is obvious for that simple example, but  the problem is when i get no rows in a subquery (in a xml path nested at 2nn or 3rd level). I know a solution if i put "NULLIF (t1.number,2) is not null it will work,   example : change to (Select    (Select NULLIF (t1.number,2) as 'e' where NULLIF (t1.number,2) is not null  FOR XML PATH('d'),type ) where NULLIF (t1.number,2) is not null  FOR XML PATH('c'),type )  the c and d path.

Comment: @Armando To be honest: Your explanations are - at least to me - absolutely unclear. My attempts are pure guessing... Nevertheless I posted a new guess, check my **UPDATE**. And please read [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)  and [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: thanks for your effort, my problem with your solution is that you are consider that you know when the element becomes null and  then you put a case ( t1.number<>2) but that is because i put a simple example. i need a solution that only change the code between the select that generates <b1> element and FOR XML PATH('b1'), type